# MySQL query to get sum of count distinct column value

Tags: mysql

I have the following mysql query.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(DISTINCT l.userid) AS 'Logins', 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated), '%M') AS 'Month'
FROM databasename.tablename l
WHERE l.action = 'loggedin' AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated)) = '2018' 
GROUP BY MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated))
```

It will produce the output of:

`Logins       Month
---------      -------
33             January
16             February`

How does the mysql query looks like to get the sum of column Logins like 49 on this example?

Thanks!

Comment: Search for `ROLLUP`

Comment: Thanks ypercubeᵀᴹ  I'm not good in mysql so I am a bit confuse how to use sum on my query with rollup.

Comment: Just add `WITH ROLLUP`, after the group by? Did you check MySQL docs?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ -  I did but the output is incorrect like this https://pastebin.com/XJJDhJS9

Comment: Why are you using different expressions in the select clause and in the group by clause? Second, how do you know that the result should be 49? Are you sure no user logged in in both Jan and Feb?

Comment: I was to slow, heres an example: Assume Jan contains A,A,B and Feb B,C,C. Jan have 2 distinct logins, so has Feb, but Jan and Feb have in total 3 distinct logins

Comment: @james - The point here is that there is no way to derive the number of unique users for a year from the number of unique users from each month.  A simple summation is, arguably, a meaningless quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with using the same expression in both select and group by:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT l.userid) AS Logins 
     , DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated), '%M') AS Month
FROM databasename.tablename l
WHERE l.action = 'loggedin' 
  AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated)) = '2018' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated), '%M');
```

If you want to count the total number of distinct logins you can add ROLLUP as ypercubeᵀᴹ suggests. You can use COALESCE to get a label for the total:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT l.userid) AS Logins 
     , COALESCE(DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated), '%M'), 'TOTAL') AS Month
FROM databasename.tablename l
WHERE l.action = 'loggedin' 
  AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated)) = '2018' 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated), '%M') WITH ROLLUP;
```

In general, the total is less than the sum of the parts. It will be the same only if the logins from Jan is disjoint with the logins from Feb.

If you instead want to sum the number of distinct logins you can do it like:

```
SELECT SUM(logins), COALESCE(Month, 'Summary') as Month
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT l.userid) AS Logins 
         , DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated), '%M') AS Month
    FROM databasename.tablename l
    WHERE l.action = 'loggedin' 
      AND YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated)) = '2018' 
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(l.timecreated), '%M')
) AS T
GROUP BY Month WITH ROLLUP;
```

This will result in the sum of the number of distinct logins for each month, which will be 49 in your case.

Comment: Thanks @Lennart. However, I got error message of `Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATE_FORMAT'`...

Comment: Sorry about that, copy paste error. I'll update the answer

Comment: You're welcome, out of curiosity which interpretation of the problem was correct?

Comment: 49 is meaningless.